# CORS and No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, routes, cors

I want to enable access from my server to an extern data. 
I have this error :

```
No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource
```

I've seen many answers about that thing, mainly unsecured solutions where Chrome protections are disabled, but I want to keep these parameters activated. However if it's only for the resource, it's fine.

So I found [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors), and I think the "Enable CORS for a Single Route" part could answer my need.

But I have no idea where, in my project, I am supposed to write such code. It can't be in the index.html, since it is in a folder "dist" writen anew each time. So the things I write in dist will be erased when I launch my project. Do I need to make a new file ? A new route ? How do you do that ?

Comment: use [`cors`](https://github.com/expressjs/cors)

Answer (score 1):

The `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` response header indicates whether the response can be shared with resources with the given origin.

---

To allow any resource to access your resource, you can specify:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
```

---

To allow https://developer.mozilla.org to access your resource, you can specify:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://developer.mozilla.org
```

---

Here is the PHP code you are probably looking for:

```
 header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
```

---

You can find more information about the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` on this page: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Allow-Origin

Comment: Hi, thanks, but I do not want to allow anything to access the resource? And where would you write this code ? I do not use php files, only js.

Comment: If you are using Node.js you should try and have a look at the documentation. This is what I found with 10 seconds of Google search: https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors

Answer (score 1):

You can use [cors](https://github.com/expressjs/cors) package to easily set these configs. A simple configuration allows all origins:

```
var cors = require('cors')
var app = express()

app.use(cors())
```

you can either allow only specific origins to access your server:

```
var cors = require('cors')
var app = express()

var whitelist = ['http://example1.com', 'http://example2.com']
var corsOptions = {
  origin: function (origin, callback) {
    if (whitelist.indexOf(origin) !== -1) {
      callback(null, true)
    } else {
      callback(new Error('Not allowed by CORS'))
    }
  }
}

app.get('/products/:id', cors(corsOptions), function (req, res, next) {
  res.json({msg: 'This is CORS-enabled for a whitelisted domain.'})
})
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to use a package for this, just set up a middleware like so

```
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
  next();
});
```

As previously mentioned, to limit access to a particular domain change the `*` to `https://whateveryourdomainis.com`. If you want allow access to a number of domains then do as @guijob has outlined

Comment: Ok, thanks, that might work, but where sould I write such code ? I only use javascript files, and I'm not sure where this belongs...